# Selenium not working Mac

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am just starting to learn web scraping with selenium. I am not sure why I am getting the following errors. I have shared the image below.
The following code seems to not work.

```
chrome_path = r"\\Users\\prateek\\Desktop\\MSc\\MWA\\chromedriver.exe"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

 # the url we want to open
url = u'https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/phones-broadband-and-sat-nav/mobile-phones-and-accessories/mobile-phones/apple-iphone-8-64-gb-space-grey-10168742-pdt.html?intcmpid=display~RR'

 # the browser will start and load the webpage
 browser.get(url)
```

There is more to it but this doesn't seem to work
Error I'm getting
[Error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAXei.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of errors. Take the time to copy, past, and format the error. Also, there must be dozens of "chromedriver must be in path" questions on this site. I suggest you do a bit more research, and share what you've learned.

Comment: Error itself describing everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `chromedriver` binary to initialize `Chrome` Web Browser on `MAC OSX` you need to pass the argument `executable_path` along with the absolute path of the `chromedriver` binary within single quotes `\` preceded by the raw switch `r` as follows :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'\Users\prateek\Desktop\MSc\MWA\chromedriver')
```

Comment: @paddy Upvote this/any Answer which is/was useful to you for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Python's `r""` literal syntax escapes all your slashes automatically, which is why it's preferred for things like file paths.

Try using

`chrome_path = r"\Users\prateek\Desktop\MSc\MWA\chromedriver.exe"`

Comment: Also, executables on Macs don't usually have `.exe` extensions, do you have the right version of chromedriver?

Comment: oh. That might be the issue. Don't think the .exe extension is the issue. And @Hans Z, I did try that but it doesn't seem to work. Gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

From [chromedriver getting started](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started), in the **Setup** section, is indicated:

> **Help WebDriver find the downloaded ChromeDriver executable**
>
> Any of these steps should do the trick:
>
> 1. include the ChromeDriver location in your PATH environment variable
> 2. include the path to ChromeDriver when instantiating webdriver.Chrome (see sample below)

You are trying to use the 2 option but you are passing the path of a wrong file (.exe file, sure, is not executable in macOS).

So, first of all you have to download (from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) ) the correct chromedriver.

Assuming you are using the current latest chrome version as browser, you have to download the **chromedriver_mac64.zip** from the 2.35 (https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.35/), extract it and insert the path to the extracted executable in your code.

For example:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/yourPath2/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/phones-broadband-and-sat-nav/mobile-phones-and-accessories/mobile-phones/apple-iphone-8-64-gb-space-grey-10168742-pdt.html?intcmpid=display~RR")
```

Be careful about your chrome browser version, because might not be supported by the chromedriver. You can know this following this [release notes](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt).

Comment: Hi, I have done that. I downloaded the chromedriver_mac64.zip and it still gives me the same error. Cant figure out why its doing that.

Comment: You have to extract the .zip and insert the path to the extracted file in your code